# How can I generate random multiples of 20 in Python?

Tags: python, random

I have built a snake game such that the snake moves 20 pixels at a time. Every time the snake stands on the same point as the apple, the game generates two random numbers to use as the coordinates for the next apple.

The problem is that if the two numbers aren't multiples of 20 then it is impossible for the snake to ever stand on the apple, as illustrated in this picture.

[image].

Is there a way to generate random numbers that are always multiples of 20?

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a random integer in the range of 0 through `(game area width / 20)`, and then multiply that by 20.

For example if your game's width is 100px, you generate a number between 0 and 5, then multiply that by 20, to get 0/20/40/60/80/100.

```
x = floor(random(0, width / 20)) * 20
```

Alternatively, you can generate a number between 1-100, and then subtract the remainder of dividing by 20:

```
x = random(0, 100)
x = x - (x % 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import random

print(random.randint(1,11)*20)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can generate a random integer between like 1 and ten. Multiply this by 20 and that will be your random move. Or choose some reasonable maximum that snake can move if 10 is not correct.